# Flask proxy server error while using in Puppeteer

Tags: python, node.js, flask, puppeteer

I am trying to create a proxy server that blocks/filter some urls and using that proxy with puppeteer but i am facing an error when i add my proxy to puppeteer args, it doesn't work and gives following error:
[error on cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmyxG.png)

and displays following on chrome:
[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wILhT.png)

## **Following is my proxy code:**

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

blocked_urls = ['/blocked_url1', '/blocked_url2']

@app.before_request
def filter_requests():
    
    requested_url = request.url.replace("http://", "https://")[:-8]
    

    if requested_url in blocked_urls:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Forbidden - URL blocked'}), 403
    else:
        try:
            response = requests.get(requested_url, timeout=1000)

            response_data = {
                'status': response.status_code,
                'headers': dict(response.headers),
                'body': response.text
            }

            return response_data
        
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            return jsonify({'error': f'Request failed - {str(e)}'}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

## **Following is my puppeteer code:**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const proxy = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'; // Replace with your proxy address
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
    {
        args: [
          `--proxy-server=${proxy}`,
          '--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>',
        ],
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        headless: false,
    }
  );

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  
  try {
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during page navigation:', error);
  }
   
  await page.waitForTimeout(50000);

  
    
  const h1Elements = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const h1s = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('h1'));
    return h1s.map(h1 => h1.textContent);
  });

  console.log('Found h1 elements:');
  h1Elements.forEach((h1, index) => {
    console.log(`${index + 1}. ${h1}`);
  });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

I have tried returning responses from proxy in many ways, like jsonify but still it is not working

Comment: Any reason you are cutting off the last 8 characters from the URL?

Comment: without cutting last 8 chars the url was like:
https://www.example.com:443/443

i thought it might be causing issue but it doesn't effect anything

Comment: Do you have the same issue with http? I mean, would it be crashed if you change `https://example.com` to `http://example.com`?

Comment: then following is what it shows me on web page puppeteer opens:

{"error":"Request failed - HTTPSConnectionPool(host='exam', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NameResolutionError(\"<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001FC1702C4D0>: Failed to resolve 'exam' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)\"))"}